# Brownian motion and Bessel process

Tags: stochastic-processes

Can you help me with the following: Prove that a geometric Brownian motion can be represented as a time-changed Bessel process
$$ \exp(B_t+vt)=R_{A_t}       $$
where $A_t= \int_{0}^t \exp(2(B_s+vs)) ds$ and $(R_t)$ is a Bessel process of parameter $2v+1$.

Comment: Please refrain from stating your question in imperative. Keep in mind, you are _asking_ someone to help you out. It would not hurt to show what you have done, and where specifically you need help.

Comment: And still no reaction [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/97484/6179)?